# Working with grouped data and difference between dates in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, difference

I Have the following example:

```
data = {"Date":['13/02/2020','13/02/2020','13/02/2020','13/02/2020','14/02/2020','14/02/2020','14/02/2020','14/02/2020',],
        "Developer":['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name3', 'Name2', 'Name2', 'Name1', 'Name4'],
        "Project":['P1','P2','P4','P3','P1','P3','P2','P4' ],
        "Hours":[1,5,8,4,8,9,4,30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My goal is to sum, grouping by Date, Developer and Project AND see the differences between following days. I can explain better.

I did the groupby function and got the following result:

```
df.groupby(["Date", "Developer"]).sum()

13/02/2020  Name1   1
            Name2   5
            Name3   12
14/02/2020  Name1   4
            Name2   17
            Name4   30
```

Until here, ok. What I want from the grouped result is a new series or data frame with the difference between the corresponding value of 14/02/2020, Name1, which is 4, and the corresponding value 13/02/2020, Name1, which is 1, resulting in 3. I want to automate this for each day and each name. I want to get a new Series/Data Frame with Date, name and the difference between the day after:

```
df_new = 
14/02/2020  Name1  3  (4 - 1)
14/02/2020  Name2  12 (17 - 5)
14/02/2020  Name3  -12 (0 - 12)
14/02/2020  Name4  30  (30 - 0)
```

And to it for the following dates and names. Can someone help me, please? I´ve tried a lot of ways but none of them worked.

Comment: _I´ve tried a lot of ways but none of them worked._ Then please share those attempts, and we can try to fix them, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
df.groupby(["Date", "Developer"]).sum().unstack().diff()
```

If you aren't ok with the stacking, then you could do

```
df.groupby(["Developer", "Date"]).sum().diff().reset_index().set_index(["Date","Developer"])
```